# What tense is this is "will have had to have seen"?

Tags: tenses, future-perfect, mood

I was making a table of the sentence "You must/have to see it." (<strike>"You see it."</strike>) in different tenses and moods in German with the English equivalent.

I ended up writing these three sentences down (in English) and was unsure about what tense they were in or if they could be considered valid sentences.

> (1) You will have had to see it.
>   (2) You will have to have seen it.
>   (3) You will have had to have seen it.

I believe that (1) is future perfect but I have no idea about (2) and (3).

Thanks!

==================================================================

I'm a native English speaker and so I have never had a formal teaching of English grammar. As an example **I will have used** future perfect many times in my life but I have only recently known of it's existence! Most of what I have learnt is from the perspective of learning German.

Comment: I don't think "you will have had to see it" and the other two examples are verb tenses of the verb "see". You have two verbs: *have* as an obbligation ("I have to see"), not as an auxiliar ("I have seen"), and *see*. "You will have had to see it" isn't future perfect (such thing would be "You will have seen). See also *Catenative verbs* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)

Comment: @Yay : Sorry I had made an error there and I've done a correction.

Comment: (1) and (3) are future perfects of "have to".  (2) is the future of "have to".  (2) and (3) have perfect infinitives after the verb "have to".

Comment: @Greg Lee (2) the Future of have to is "you will have to see it."  This is something else.

Comment: @Yay: Also thanks for linking to the article about Catenative verbs. I had been thinking about them the other day but did not realise that that is what they are.

Comment: Perhaps a conjugation table will help you. The best conjugation tables  I have found on the Internet are by www.verbix.com. -to be: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html - to have: http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/have.html -  There are tables for any verb you want.

Comment: @TomB, Certainly it's something else.  As I said, (2) has a perfect infinitive after the verb "have to".

Comment: I found [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked) to be an informative link about the **perfect infinitive** which @GregLee mentioned.

Comment: From the same [website](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked): "We can use the perfect infinitive in a ...a non-finite clause."  So am I correct in thinking that all the parts after "to" are part of a non-finite clause and so don't have any influence on the tense of the sentence?

Comment: Yes, the parts after "to" are part of the complement to the main verb and play no role in determining the tense of the main clause.

Comment: @GregLee: Thank you for clarifying that. I think in hindsight, my question should have been regarding the role of these "after 'to'" parts! Thanks. :D

Comment: I think it's also important to note that in most cases this type of sentence structure would not sound native. I think a native speaker would probably use the *conditional* tense ("would have" rather than "will have").

Comment: All these sentences are in the present tense.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I disagree with you there and so do a few others ^^

Answer (score 0):

Numbers 1 and 3 are as stated both forms of the Future Perfect (will + have + Past Participle) e.g. You will have had dinner by the time I arrive.  Just add had + infinitive and you have obligation.

> (2) You will have to have seen it.

If we use this in an example we can say something like

**He will have to have bought the tickets before he sees the movie**

I think this is a deduction and you need to change **will** to **would** for it to be logical and distinguish itself from the Future Perfect.

For example:
**He would have to have bought the tickets before he saw the movie.**

I don't think the example with **will** and **see** is correct.

I think the example as originally stated is just an incorrect use of the Future Tense.

Comment: You haven’t seen it? Well, by the time you graduate you will have to have seen it- it’s required for your major.

Comment: I see that example as forced and difficult to understand.  That idea is clearer as "you haven't seen it?  Well, by the time you graduate you will have."

Comment: @TomB: I didn't realise that "obligation" was classed as a [mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood).

Comment: @TomB: I don't follow your sentence "I don't think the example with will and see is correct." from your first line it looks like you believe it to be a form of the Future Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

'you will see' = future habitual

'you will have seen' = future perfect

the rest all contain control verbs (you could replace have*/had* with want/wanted...)

'you will have* to see' = future habitual (inf habitual)

'you will have* to have seen' = future habitual (inf perfect)

'you will have had* to have seen' = future perfect (inf perfect)